# Codeigniter connecting to multiple databases

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have been using these lines of code for connecting multiple databases in codeigniter but getting error. My new db connection is for new_group.

```
$this->new_group = $this->CI->load->database('new_group', TRUE); 
$q = $this->new_group->query("SELECT* FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Call to a member function database() on a non-object.

Waiting for response. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/145901/

```
$db['new_group']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

I didnt try...

Comment: You need to `$second_db = $this->load->database('new_group');` first and then use `$second_db->query('SQL Query');` to use it (it's recommended to use a class property to 'globalize' your second database connection - `$this->second_db = ... `)

Comment: I have to fetch data from 2 databases one after other so that i am using this. first declaring $this->new_group = $this->CI->load->database('new_group', TRUE); and then executing my query on db.

Answer (score 2):

remove ->CI from the load command

```
$this->new_group = $this->load->database('new_group', TRUE); 
$q = $this->new_group->query("SELECT* FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC");
```

or you have to load the CI object first:

```
$this->CI =& get_instance();
$this->new_group = $this->CI->load->database('new_group', TRUE); 
$q = $this->new_group->query("SELECT* FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Comment: ...so if my answer worked - why did you 'accept' the other answer as correct? lol...